# Pagination with swipe Gesture swift 3

Tags: swift3, pagination, tableview, viewcontroller, uiswipegesturerecognizer

How to implement swipe gesture between two View Controller and called pagination in it for multiple data loading with swipe and change ViewController with data  according to Rest Api data .

Comment: what u tried?can u please share  your code.

Comment: i have two viewcontroller , that two viewcontroller swipe each other and chnage pages as per swipe .. in that i want to implement pagination for data change as per swipe pages .. data change as per my Rest Api URL @tabassum

Comment: You can try UIPageViewController.

Comment: pagination concept @RatneshJain